# TimeoutError when using smtplib

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email using smtp in python, but the code failed. In the console it says:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

```
import smtplib

my_email = "someemail@gmail.com"
password = "krwznillogwscftw"

connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="anotheremail@gmail.com", msg="Hello")
connection.close()
```

Comment: Try with `smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)`

Comment: SMTP traditionally uses port 25, but if you are on a generic consumer broadband connection, your ISP has firewalled that port to Gehenna and back to curb spam. Modern SMTP submission uses port 587 with STARTTLS, though some providers also use the legacy port 465 over SSL.